# Where on Stack Exchange should I ask questions such as "What's the best tutorial?"?

Tags: discussion, scope

Where on Stack Exchange should I ask questions like "What's the best initial tutorial for..." or "What is the best way to learn..."?

Comment: Nowhere[.](http://derp)

Comment: ok  :'( so where can i post a question like that?

Comment: SO/SE isn't the whole internets.  There are plenty of outlets that serve markets not served here.

Comment: some examples ?

Comment: In order to give you some, I'd have to do the same thing you would--search for them.

Comment: Here's the best tutorial: http://www.chillibreeze.com/tutorials/Tutorial-HowtoWriteATutorial.asp There, now you needn't ask that question.

Comment: @adamdavis dead link.

Comment: @JeffPuckettII Here: https://web.archive.org/web/20131021005656/http://www.chillibreeze.com/tutorials/Tutorial-HowtoWriteATutorial.asp

Answer (score 15):

Just don't. It is extraordinarily rare for a "what is the best X" or "give me a list of X" question to be appropriate for any Stack Exchange site.

If you have a more specific problem, please ask about it directly. Beginner-level questions are welcome on most sites.

Comment: Is softwarerecs.stackexchange.com the extraordinarily rare exception? I love that site and I wish there was a similar community rated knowledge base for tutorials and examples. Searching through the jungle turns up a lot of junk that could have easily been filtered with some down votes. Similarly, up votes would help the cream rise to the top.

Comment: Yes, it is. That site didn't exist back when this answer was written... I don't think anyone back in 2011 would have predicted that the team would ever allow an entire site just for recommendations.