# Should we blacklist the tutorials tag

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, tag-block-request

The [tutorials tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/tutorials) on Stack Overflow seems to attract quite a few problem questions.

On one hand there are the:

- I [need tutorial](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7855130/good-resource-to-learn-javascript-closures) for XYZ kthx plz.

And on the other hand there are the:

- Some people treat it as a blessing to post full on [tutorials](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7942597/open-in-menu-tutorial-for-ios).

I do not think this tag is adding much, should we ban/remove it?

Answer (score 8):

The [tutorial](/questions/tagged/tutorial) tag should probably be removed from most — probably *all* — of those questions as a [meta tag](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/08/the-death-of-meta-tags/). Those questions are not *about* "tutorial" but tagged that way to describe the purpose of the post (i.e. a meta tag).

If a user wants to post a tutorial to share something they learned, [that should be fine](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/89333/whats-the-best-way-to-post-a-tutorial-on-so). Those questions should be tagged by subject of the post.

If the question is *requesting* a tutorial, [that's not generally a good question for Stack Overflow anyway](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/109941/where-on-stack-overflow-should-whats-the-best-tutorial-like-questions-be-ask). It's still not a good tag for the question.

About 172 of the 1,964 questions tagged [tutorial](/questions/tagged/tutorial) have already been closed. The rest seem to be mistagged or really poor questions… so it's been demonstrated to be a problem.

Perhaps banning the tag outright will give them enough pause to avoid asking the question outright. *wishful thinking*

Comment: All tags are meta tags, eventually there won't be many useful ones left.

Comment: @LanceRoberts: I'm sorry, I don't understand what you are saying. The "Death of Meta Tags" post linked above talks about a very *specific* class of tags we explicitly discourage.

Comment: I'm not sure what you don't understand.  All tagging is a way of categorizing something, which is a meta activity.  They're all just labels that tell you what's in the post, and not the __content__ of the post.  Specifically in this case, `tutorial` can easily be applied to any post and denote the content.

Comment: You would have to match it up with another tag, but you'd have to do that with `excel` and `vba` for example, if you needed to denote that specific circumstance.  If your search for `java` right now you end up with 171,100 questions, but if you searched for that with `tutorials` you'd get down to 1964.  I don't understand why you guys who hate the category tags want to make it so hard to search, and cut flow from the search engines.

Comment: Search is already broken on our sites, please don't keep making it harder.

Answer (score 2):

I think [tutorial](/questions/tagged/tutorial) should be kept, so that those who want to search just for tutorial oriented posts will be able to bring them up.  The point of having a tag system is so that you can find what you're looking for, if we keep getting rid of general category tags, we just make it harder for a user to search for what they need.  We also cut down on the search engines finding those posts, therefore cutting down on traffic to the site.

So, if we have Q&A that either are tutorials or are asking for references to them, we should have the tag.  **Whether we should have those kind of questions at all is a different topic.**