# Your edit couldn't be submitted because: sorry, the X tag is not allowed

Tags: support, tags

I tried to improve a question in StackOverflow which has a tag [tutorials](/questions/tagged/tutorials). At the time of saving, I got the error as given below.

```
Oops! Your edit couldn't be submitted because:
    sorry, the 'tutorials' tag is not allowed.
```

What should I do?
Should I do remove the tag and save it?
If the tag is not allowed, StackOverflow can remove the tag from all question, why didn't they do it?
If it is not possible, they can automatically remove the tag at the time of editing so that
 we can avoid removing the tag manually.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Removing a tag is usually a cleanup effort, where questions that have the tag are fixed and improved before the tag is removed (see [the homework tag cleanup](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/147100/the-homework-tag-is-now-officially-deprecated), for example). This is especially important in the case of the [tutorials](/questions/tagged/tutorials) tag, [which the community has agreed is problematic](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/110667/should-we-blacklist-the-tutorials-tag).

Thus, in this case the right thing to do (since you're already improving the question) is remove the tag and save it.

Comment: At the time of editing a post, StackOverflow automatically removing some silly stuffs like 'Hi', 'Hello' (http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts/93989#93989). The same way they should automatically remove banned tags.

Comment: @habeebperwad. The point of not removing the tags automatically is that most questions with that tag are problematic. Simply removing the tag is not enough: the questions should be cleaned up too. Since you're doing that anyway, go ahead and remove the tag while you're at it.